# Wrong Answer for $m=40$ with Shor's Algorithm

Tags: modules

I am using Shor's Algorithm to find the prime factors for $m=40$. Here is my shot.

Step $1$: Choose a random $1< a <40$. So I chose $a=9$.

Step $2$: Find $r$ = order$(9,40)$. This results in $r=2$. (confirmed my answer [here](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/order.html))

Step $3$: Make sure $r$ is even and $a^{r/2} \ncong -1 \mod{40}$. In my case $9^{2/2} \ncong -1 \mod{40}$.

Step $4$: $p = \gcd(a^{r/2}-1,m) = \gcd(8,40)$ and $q = \gcd(a^{r/2}-1,m) = \gcd(10,40)$. I surprisingly get the values $p=8$ and $q=10$.

In which step did I make a mistake?

Comment: I don't see the problem - both $8$ and $10$ are indeed factors of $40$, aren't they?

Comment: @MiloBrandt but doesn't Shor's Algorithm give you $m=p . q$ with $p$ and $q$ prime numbers?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only gives you two numbers that are factors of $m$.  If $m$ is the product of two primes, it may be that you get $m = p.q$, but in the example you have chosen, 40 is not the product of two primes.